# At JSON.stringify , parsererrorSyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, aem, aem-6

At JSON.stringify , my javascript is giving the following message in the console.

parsererrorSyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

```
var contentData =     {
                "Location": {
                    "City": "Bangalore Urban",
                    "State": "Karnataka",
                    "Country": "IN"
                },
                "Packages": [
                    "3 days and 4 nights"
                ],
                "Hotels": "Vividus",
                "Offers": [
                    "Enjoy up to 20% Savings",
                    "Hotel Discounts, Just for Booking Early.2 nights B&B to include first night dinner"
                ],
                "Activities": [
                    "scuba diving",
                    "swimming"
                ]
            }




        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/my/reco/pkg.',
            data : JSON.stringify(contentData),
            async : false,    // I get this message both with false and true here.
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success : function(data) {
                 console.log(data);

            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, message) {
                console.log("error"+jqXHR+textStatus+message);
            }
        });
```

When I put a debugger on in chrome, I see the error at the point JSON.stringify.

I have validated both json and the javascript code, both seems to be syntactically correct.

I can find the request json in the network tab under header section of chrome.

What am I doing wrong or missing here ?

Comment: What does contentData look like? Also does the server return actual JSON or perhaps a 404 page?

Comment: kindly close the server and run it again It might help.

Comment: why not send it as **JSON** and add **dataType: 'json'** ?

Comment: you don't need to stringify your data if you have model on server side

Comment: @ElyasEsna but request is not even reaching the server side.

Comment: can you share the server side code

Comment: also as @AbdelrahmanGobarah mentioned you have to add this line to your ajax part `dataType: 'json'`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do `JSON.stringify` in `JSON.stringify(contentData)`. You can just send an object. So, send data without it.

Answer (score -2):

the error you don't assign the object to variable **contentData**

put at first **var contentData =**

```js
var contentData = {
  "Location": {
    "City": "Bangalore Urban",
    "State": "Karnataka",
    "Country": "IN"
  },
  "Packages": [
    "3 days and 4 nights"
  ],
  "Hotels": "Vividus",
  "Offers": [
    "Enjoy up to 20% Savings",
    "Hotel Discounts, Just for Booking Early.2 nights B&B to include first night dinner"
  ],
  "Activities": [
    "scuba diving",
    "swimming"
  ]
}



console.log(JSON.stringify(contentData));
```